# When do I use square brackets around routerLink in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax, templates, routing

In Angular 2 (currently 2.0.0-rc.6), `routerLink` is used as a directive to indicate a path we wish to follow in our routing, e.g. in response to clicking a link.

However, in the documentation both of the following are used:

- `routerLink`
- `[routerLink]`

I don't understand when I should use which. The [Basics / Template Syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) page discusses how square brackets are used for, among other things, setting a property of a directive. To me, that sounds like I should use square brackets in this case but the documentation shows otherwise.

When I initially pondered this question, I thought it might have something to do with the use of a plain string, e.g. `routerLink="/heroes"` versus something more complex and/or dynamic such as a link parameters array, e.g. `[routerLink]="['/hero', hero.id]"`. However, the following two direct quotes from the documentation show that that is not the answer:

From [Developer Guide / Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) (about half way down the page):

```
<a routerLink="/crisis-center/admin" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Admin</a>
```

From [API Reference / RouterLink](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html):

```
<a [routerLink]="/user/bob">link to user component</a>
```

The data-binding source on the right side of the equals sign in each of those examples has the same format, i.e. is just a string.

So, when do I use which?

Comment: [This](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax) provides a good overview of the binding modes, and the syntax to use for each.

Comment: Yes that page does provide a good overview of some relevant general principles, and in fact I link to that page in my question. I don't think, however, that it answers my specific question. I suppose my question could be re-phrased as "When should I _not_ use square brackets for routerLink?" which, I believe, is not addressed by that page, at least not in a clear, obvious way.

Comment: You could always try both, and see if there's a difference in behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever something is in square brackets the content gets evaluated. Probably the reference was wrong because `<a [routerLink]="/user/bob">` won't work because the code `/user/bob` has syntax error, actually it's a malformed Regex.

I checked the reference, now it has `<a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']">` and `<a routerLink="/user/bob">`, both of them are correct.